# Iterate Through MenuStrips

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I find answers for iterating through menustrip items but no luck for iterating through menuStrips (let's say I have a few contextMenuStrip in a Form).

```
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
{ 
    if(c is ContextMenuStrip)
    {
        // This doesn't work. I figured out contextmenustrips are not
        // holding in this.Controls
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use a debugger, step through your code, inspect variables and the like.

Comment: Try this: this.components.Components

Comment: As @Nick says, if you look in the InitializeComponent() method in the constructor for your form, you'll see that the ContextMenuStrip will have been added to this.components.

Comment: @Aaron thank you guys, I learned something new.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var ctrl in this.components.Components)
{
    if (ctrl is ContextMenuStrip ctx)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ctx.GetType().Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need this for any form you need to access the private fields of it using reflection. Because ContextMenuStrip is a private member.
This is a method that works for any given form:

```
private IEnumerable<ContextMenuStrip> EnumerateContextMenus(Form form)
{
  const BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
  var fields = form.GetType().GetFields(bindingFlags);
  return fields
    .Where(x => x.FieldType == typeof(ContextMenuStrip))
    .Select(x => x.GetValue(form) as ContextMenuStrip);
}
```

Comment: This also worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ContextMenuStrips are part of components, not controls.

```
foreach(var c in components.Components)
{ 
   if(c is ContextMenuStrip)
   {
   }
}
```

OR

```
 ContextMenuStrip cStrip = null;    
 foreach(var c in components.Components)
 { 
   cStrip = c as ContextMenuStrip;
   if(cStrip!=null)
   {
   }
 }
```